# Rails - validate 25 lines in a text box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use the `validates` method on one of my text fields in a model so that the end user must enter at least 25 lines (separated with an enter key). So for now i validate the presence of the input so it won't be blank:

```
validates :lines, :presence => true
```

This must use some regex to check for maybe the presence of at least 24 '`\n`' ?
How can i accomplish that in my model?

EDIT: values need to  be utf8

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to do it with `validate` method:

```
validate do
  errors.add(:lines, "must be at least 25 lines") if lines.lines.to_a.size < 25
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do it with regexp, try something like

```
/([^\n]*\n[^\n]*){24,}/
```

but it counts empty lines as well.